# Is there a way to hide that a message was edited in Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am writing a reaction role bot and I want to add a rolemenu refresh command. This command simply recreates the embed and edits the message to replace the embed with the new one. However, this creates a nasty `modified` tag on top of the message as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnUJw.png)

Is there a way to edit a message without leaving the `modified` tag on it, or maybe to delete the tag ?

I've looked into the attributes and flags of [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message), [edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit), and [edited_at](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edited_at) and tried to change that attribute but it didn't remove the tag from the message

EDIT : Deleting the message and sending it again would not work since I want the order of the messages to stay the same, I just want to modify the content of the message

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 2):

No but you can delete and send message again.

Comment: Yes but this isn't the same as editing the message since the order of the message in the channel would change if I delete it and send it again, I'll edit my question to add that I want to keep the order